# Efficient random number list sum in Racket

Tags: list, optimization, vector, scheme, racket

What would be the most efficient way to first generate and then sum a list of random integers in Racket?

I am trying to implement an equivalent of the code in https://scottlocklin.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/only-fast-languages-are-interesting but I can only come up with slow imlpementations.

My first naive attempt (not random integers, but anyway):

```
(define (sum-list l)
  (if (null? l)
      0
      (+ (first l) (sum-list (rest l)))))

(define avector 
    (build-vector 3000000 add1))

(time (sum-list avector))
```

Please note that the efficient part of the code should only be the actual sum of the list, not the generation.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you were interested in saving space, you could use a lazy version of build-vector (e.g. [build-list from Lazy Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/lazy/index.html)) so that only one element from it need be in memory at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple version, using `vector's:

```
#lang racket    

(define N 3000000)
(define avector 
    (for/vector #:length N ([i (in-range N)]) (random)))

(define (sum-vec v)
  (for/fold ([i 0.0]) ([e (in-vector v)]) (+ e i)))

(time (sum-vec avector))
```

That runs in about 250 ms on my machine.

If we switch to using `flvector`:

```
#lang racket

(require racket/flonum)

(define N 3000000)
(define avector 
    (for/flvector #:length N ([i (in-range N)]) (random)))

(define (sum-vec v)
  (for/fold ([i 0.0]) ([e (in-flvector v)]) (+ e i)))

(time (sum-vec avector))
```

Then it runs in about 60 ms.

If we change it to use Typed Racket:

```
#lang typed/racket

(require racket/flonum)

(define N 3000000)
(define avector 
    (for/flvector #:length N ([i (in-range N)]) (random)))

(: sum-vec : FlVector -> Float)
(define (sum-vec v)
  (for/fold ([i 0.0]) ([e (in-flvector v)]) (+ e i)))

(time (sum-vec avector))
```

Now it runs in about 20 ms.

Comment: That's a great reply, thanks a lot. I am taking my first steps in Racket and this single comment gives me enough material to study for a while!

Typed Racket looks specially interesting. It reminds me of Ocaml-style signatures.